# Modifying freeRTOS emulator

Tags: freertos

I am new to freeRTOS and would like to modify the OS to accommodate some new hardware. I would like to do this in an emulator, which could be either Windows or Linux (preferred).

I have installed and operated freeRTOS in both systems and it all works. I want to tweak some of the freeRTOS internals, rebuild the emulated freeRTOS, and test the result.

I am looking for some direction and hints on the best way to go about this task.

Answer (score 2):

Such a massively open ended question with no indication of what it is you want to achieve makes this unanswerable.  There is some info on how the Windows simulator/emulator/port works here http://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Windows-Simulator-Emulator-for-Visual-Studio-and-Eclipse-MingW.html

Comment: Nothing massive. Suppose I wanted to change hook.c. Change a conditional stanza. ie change a #if / #endiif to a if / endif. Rebuild and stand back for the results. Just want to play with the code and rebuild the emulator.

Comment: I guess I was expecting a make file and don't see one.